# Finding heat capacity from an energy curve versus temperature

Tags: plotting

I plotted an energy curve from the following points:

```
{0.01,0.6004},{0.1,0.6354},{0.5,1.032},{1.1,1.8516},{1.5,2.4167},{2.0,3.1576}
```

What I want to do is compute the heat capacity form this curve by calculating the slope along the curve at various points and plotting the results. I tried using the following code:

```
heatcap[t]=(energy[t+.01]-energy[t])/.02;
Plot[heatcap[t],{t,0.2,1.99}].
```

All that I got from this was a grid and no points. I am really baffled by this and need some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not give an explicit explanation of you data list, I suppose they are in the form of `(temperature, energy)` with `SI unit`.

```
energyVsTemperature = {{0.01,0.6004}, {0.1,0.6354}, {0.5,1.032}, {1.1,1.8516}, {1.5, 2.4167}, {2.0, 3.1576}};
experimentData = ListPlot[energyVsTemperature, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[.02]}];
```

Instead of your formula `heatcap[t]=(energy[t+.01]-energy[t])/.02`, I will use the derivative of an interpolation function for `energyVsTemperature` to calculate the `heat capacity`.

Firstly, an interpolation function for `heat capacity`, i.e. `heatCap`, is made with `Interpolation[...]`:

```
heatCap = Interpolation[energyVsTemperature];
interpolatedHeatCapPlot = Plot[heatCap[t], {t, 0.01, 1.99}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Validate our interpolation function for `heat capacity`:

```
Show[{experimentData, interpolatedHeatCapPlot}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Temperature", "Energy"}, 
    Epilog -> Inset[Column[{
        LineLegend[{Blue}, {"Interpolated function"}], 
        PointLegend[{Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]}, {"Experiment data"}]}], 
      Scaled[{.8, .3}]]]
```

[image]

We can use `Manipulate[...]` to obtain the `heat capacity` at each `Temperature`:

```
Manipulate[Show[{experimentData, interpolatedHeatCapPlot, Graphics[{PointSize[.03], Point[{loc[[1]], heatCap[loc[[1]]]}]}]}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Temperature", "Energy"}, PlotLabel ->"Current heat capacity = " <> ToString[D[heatCap[t], t] /. t -> loc[[1]]],
  ImageSize -> {480, 320}, Epilog -> {Inset[Column[{
      LineLegend[{Blue}, {"Interpolated function"}],
      PointLegend[{Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]}, {"Experiment data"}]}],
    Scaled[{.8, .3}]]}],
  {{loc, {0.3, heatCap[0.3]}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}, AppearanceElements -> None]
```

[image]